# Action Script - how to access label component defined in mxml file within action script class method?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I have a label component in a mxml file like below

```
<mx:Label x="700" y="409" text="Label" id="lble" width="131" height="41"/>
```

if i want to access it and change its text content within a method defined in action script class that i have written, how to do it?

```
lble.text="test";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID attribute makes it a private variable within the class or component, so

```
lble.text = "test";
```

is just fine.

You *are* talking about doing this within the same component or class, right? If not you should bind the value to a variable and use getters and setters, like so

```
[Bindable]
private var _labelText:String;

public function get labelText() : String {
  return _labelText;
}

public function set labelText(value:String) : void {
  _labelText = value;
}
```

and then

```
<mx:Label text="{_labelText}"/>
```

Comment: I used "_labelText" as the private variable name just for illustration purposes. Change it to whatever you want, but follow the pattern above and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

To access the label, you have to import the Label component before the class definition, so it can be accessed:

```
import mx.controls.Label;
```

Then, declare the reference to the label in your class body:

```
public var lble:Label;
```

And, finally, you can address the label to manipulate it:

```
lble.text = "Hello world!";
```